# Spring Security: Java configuration with data source

Tags: configuration, spring-security

Not so long ago Spring presented a java based configuration for the Spring Security module. I try to migrate from XML to Java configuration.
Here is my test project: https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/security-spr

pom.xml was updated:

spring.version = 3.2.4.RELEASE
spring.security.version = 3.1.4.RELEASE

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
...
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
```

Then I have added a new java config class instead of spring-security.xml

```
package com.sprsec.init;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import com.sprsec.service.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.userDetailsService(new CustomUserDetailsService())
            .authorizeUrls()
            .antMatchers("/sec/moderation.html").hasRole("MODERATOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/user-login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/success-login.html")
            .failureUrl("/error-login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html");
    }

}
```

After that I changed my Initializaer.class to:

```
package com.sprsec.init;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class Initializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Remark:

- spring-security.xml was deleted
- A line of code @ImportResource("classpath:spring-security.xml") was deleted in WebAppConfig.java
- Filter declaration in web.xml was removed

When I try to run the application on a server I get:

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppConfig': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor.setAdvice(Lorg/aopalliance/aop/Advice;)V

Can someone give an advice what can be a reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into some dependency conflict. Run `maven dependency:tree` to figure out which dependencies are used and find conflicting ones. Also the use of the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) might help.

Looking at your sample project you are using Spring 3.1.3 and the same for Spring Security, you want to have seperate properties for spring and spring security.

```
<properties>
  <hibernate.version>4.1.7.Final</hibernate.version>
  <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
  <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
  <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE<spring.security.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

As for Spring Security you might want to try out the new [3.2.0.RC1](http://www.springsource.org/node/22675) as that already includes the new spring security javaconfig with improvements and some convenience superclasses.

A final note on your configuration, as that is flawed, you are duplicating your bean instances as you are loading the same configuration twice (duplicating your whole configuration), both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` use the `WebAppConfig` for configuration. This could effectively render your security useless.

Submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/security-spr/pull/3) which should give you some pointers on how to fix the issue at hand.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response

I have done all fixes which you recommend and now I haven't any errors while I start a server

But a new issue is an empty work directory of the project after I have started the server. Very strange behaviour

Comment: Check if it starts. As I mentioned in the commit you should add the maven war plugin and configure it for the missing web.xml (which you should remove).